# Hindi Unicode supported by Mobile phones

Tags: unicode, fonts, sms, hindi, language-translation

I'm currently doing a project on Language translation where I'm converting an English text to Hindi. I'm trying to send the converted Hindi text to a mobile phone, but the message could not be displayed on my phone as there is no hindi font. But I have seen mobile network operators sending their promos in Hindi which my mobile reads like charm. I would like to know if there is any unicode or some other conversion of the text so that the hindi text will be displayed on my phone?

Comment: What character set and encoding is your Hindi text in currently?

Comment: That depends on how the text is sent and to what phone. If SMS, the correct encoding can be carrier specific. Email? Depends on what the phone can handle... We need more details to really be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also thought to start such program. I maintained the Unicode characters of all the hindi letters in a file.

```
2305
2309
2309 अआइईउऊऋएऐओऔअंअँअंअः
2325 कखगघङ 
2330 चछजझञ 
2335 टठडढण 
2340 तथदधनऩ
2346 पफबभम
2351 यरऱलळऴव
2358 शषसह 2361
2364 च़चऽचाचि ---- -upto च॔ 2388
2392 क़ख़ग़ज़ड़ड़ढ़फ़य़ॠॡ 2401
2402 चॢचॣ। ॥ 2405
2406 ०१२३४५६७८९
```

I hope you are having 16-bit characters to store hindi characters.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you please suggest a method on how will I be able to use this file to send the message?

Comment: @tripleee! Ya thanks for correcting. Its Unicode. Edited my answer

Comment: @user1640534! How are you doing it now? I think simply storing them in 16-bit characters and sending should work.